# basic question about dual space in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been reading 'Introduction to Lie Algebras and Representation Theory-Humphreys'.
The following is the text in page 19.

Let $s$=diag($a_1, a_2, ... , a_m$). Let E be the vector space spanned by $a_1, ... , a_m$. We want to show that $s=0$, equivalently, that $E=0$. Since $E$ has finite dimension, it will suffice to show that the dual space $E^*$ is $0$.

I have a question about the last sentence. If we show that $E^*=0$, then $(E^*)^*=0$. Since $E$ is finite dimensional, it is isomorphic to $(E^*)^*$. So we're done. Did I understand the text correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why the hypothesis of finite dimension is needed.

If $E$ is non-zero, so is $E^\ast$, just pick $e \in E$ and consider the projection to $\langle e \rangle$ (I mean, write $E = \langle e\rangle \oplus S$ and consider $\lambda e +s \mapsto \lambda$). Conversely, if $E^\ast = 0$, then as you say $(E^\ast)^\ast  = 0$ and the canonical map $\jmath \colon x \in E \mapsto \mathbf{ev}_x \in (E^\ast)^\ast$ is always injective so $E = 0$.